# How to retrieve a multidimensional array using json object?

Tags: android, json, multidimensional-array

I created an app that stream video from server, on server side (PHP) I use this code to pass the MySQL query result via JSON array contain a result of video title size and views.

```
 $query="select * from video_tble ;";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $respones_result=array();
 $response_result=$row;
 echo json_encode(array("server_response_result"=>$response_result));
```

But I don't know how to retrieve a multidimensional array using JSON object.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject(json);
 JSONArray jsonArray1=jsonObject1.getJSONArray("server_response_result");
 JSONObject JO1=jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0);
 String [] title =...?
```

If it was a name value pair then I follow this strategy:

```
 String title1=JO1.getString("title");
```

But I don't know what to do on multidimensional array.

Comment: Could you please post the JSON response?

Comment: this is not a php question, remove the tag

Comment: `getJSONArray()` first, then `getString()`.

Comment: @Krrishnaaaa ->

{"server_response_result":[{"videoid":"1","videotitle":"Metro Shoes","userid":"7","category":"Fashion","dou":"0000-00-00","rate":"3","vstatus":"A","vcount":"321","location":"adstreamer\\uploads\\ramesh@gmail.com\\1.mp4"},{"videoid":"2","videotitle":"Lijn the bus","userid":"7","category":"App","dou":"0000-00-00","rate":"4","vstatus":"A","vcount":"145","location":"adstreamer\\uploads\\ramesh@gmail.com\\2.mp4"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need a for loop like this

```
for(int i;i<jsonArray1.size();i++){
    JSONObject JO1=jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
    String title1=JO1.getString("title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse this json

```
{
    "server_response_result": [{
        "videoid": "1",
        "videotitle": "Metr‌​o Shoes",
        "userid": "7",
        "category": "Fashion",
        "dou": "0000-00-00",
        "rate": "3",
        "vstatus": "A",
        "vcount": "321",
        "location": "adstreamer\\uploads\\ramesh@gmail.com\\1.mp4"
    }, {
        "videoid": "2",
        "videotitle": "Lijn the bus",
        "userid": "7",
        "category": "App",
        "dou": "0000-00-00",
        "rate": "4",
        "vstatus": "A",
        "vcount": "145",
        "location": "adstreamer\\uploads\\ramesh@gmail.com\\2.mp4"
    }]
}
```

You have to do following steps (saying you have the server response in `jsonObject`.

```
ArrayList<SomeModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray serverResponseResult = jsonObject.getJsonArray("server_response_result");
for (int i = 0; i < serverResponseResult.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject result = serverResponseResult.get(i);
    String videoId = result.getString("videoid");
    String videoTitle = result.getString("videotitle");
    ...
    // instead of using String, set the values in the model class
    modelList.add(/* model */);
}
```

Comment: thank you both for your effort & i understand your concept but now it gives an exception saying
"org.json.JSONException: No value for server_response_result"

Comment: thank you both it works.. error was i tried to parse 2 array at same time..